# Solr 9.3.1 not returning JSONP response correctly

Tags: solr, jsonp

I have been working on upgrading our Solr stack from v7 to v9.3.1.   I have recreated my cores and populated them fresh, but when I request a JSONP callback with wt=json, I just get JSON back instead of a wrapped callback.   If I use wt=python, I get the callback as expected but I am looking to just have a standard json output

The same call works as expected on my old version

I have amended the wt and get a proper wrapper on the python datatype.

wt=json&json.wrf=ng_jsonp_callback_0 on Solr 9.3.0

`{   "responseHeader":{     "status":0,     "QTime":9,     "params":{`

wt=python&json.wrf=ng_jsonp_callback_0 on Solr 9.3.0

`ng_jsonp_callback_0({   'responseHeader':{     'status':0,     'QTime':28,`

wt=json&json.wrf=ng_jsonp_callback_0 on Solr 7.3.1

`ng_jsonp_callback_0({   "responseHeader":{     "status":400,     "QTime":206,     "params":{`